# Al editar un publicación de wordpress con fecha acf, esta se modifica sola

Tags: wordpress, date, wordpress-plugin

Tengo una página creada en Wordpress y utilizo el plugin *Advanced Custom Fields*, concretamente tengo un campo de tipo fecha. Al crear la publicación funciona correctamente, indico una fecha en el calendario, pero cuando entro a editar la publicación (no la fecha) la fecha marca un día anterior y si actualizo los datos este se modifica, pero yo no lo he cambiado. Me gustaría que la fecha se mantuviera si yo no la cambio.

Comment: Hola, parece que el plugin toma la edicion como fecha de creacion, intenta entrar a la configuracion del plugin a ver si dispone de la opcion de que al editar un post este no modifique su fecha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucioné con esto:
Edité el archivo "includes/api/api-helpers.php" y cambia de

```
return date_i18n($format, $unixtimestamp);
```

a:

```
return wp_date($format, $unixtimestamp);
```

Además me aseguré de que la zona horaria de Wordpress fuera la correcta:
Ajustes > Generales > Zona horaria